# Pubsub model vs point to point in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, publish-subscribe

I am new to kafka so having hard time undertsnading the pubsub model.
Lets say i have a topic with 2 partitions(lets call them partition1,partition2)

I have 3 consumers where

consumer1,consumer2 --> belong to consumerGroup1 and each are tied to partition1 and partition2

consumer3 --> belongs to consumerGroup2 and the only consumer in this group.It reads from partition1

lets us says all 3 consumers read from partition1 which has 5 messages

My doubts are,

1.Does all 5 messages in partition1 reach to each of the consumers,ie, consumer1 and consumer3 ? Or do they share messages one after the other ,as the offset maintained by the kafka mightnot have idea about the consumer belonging to same consumer group or different consumer groups?Is this called pub-sub pattern?

2.If i want to have point to point patter,all i need to do,is puut all consumers in same consumer group.Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

Two groups do not share messages and multiple consumers in the same group cannot be consuming from the same partition. There's also no ordering guarantee that says "consumer1" is assigned to "partition1" (it could very likely happen that "consumer1" dies and both partitions are assigned to "consumer2"). The "consumer3" would read from both partitions if it is the only member of that group.

Offsets are tracked by group, not the consumer `client.id`.

Kafka is always publish-subscribe. Point-to-Point models would not be using a message broker (for example, a TCP client-server such as HTTP or gRPC)